# Building .NET COMInterop project without first registering the COM service

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows, com

I am building a C# UI to interact with a COM Service (.exe).  The VS2005 COM project outputs a valid typelib (TLB), which is referenced by the C# project.  However, the VS2005 C# project insists that the service be registered in order to build the C# project, even though the typelib appears perfectly valid when examined with the OLE Object Viewer.

We would rather not register the service on the build server, if possible.  Further, debug builds cannot register the COM object as a service, since this makes debugging in general, and startup code in particular, more difficult (can't use F5 - Start Debugging).

What should I look for in order to get this working?  Do I need to register just the TypeLib?  If so, why would COMInterop insist on having the service or TLB registered in order to build correctly (and, is there a command-line tool for this on Win2003 with VS2005)?

If I recall correctly, once apon a time I built a C# web service which referenced the Win2003 firewall COM object, but we built it on Win2000 (which does not have such a thing) simply by referencing the TLB file with no registration required, so I don't understand why this should be a problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a -regtypelib command to the COM service, which calls the AtlRegisterTypeLib function but does not register the service.  Suboptimal because it will leave registery entries on the build server, but quick and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create interop assembly using [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(VS.80).aspx) tool. And add reference to this assembly in your project instead of typelib. In this case building will not require registered com server.

If you do not want to ship yet another assembly, you can extract interface description from generated interop assembly using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and include them into project as source files.

Comment: Upvoted your answer, but it was easier to just register the typelib.